# Changing IE settings with Python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, settings

this is my first question for me, i hope you will understand what i'm saying.

So, at my work, we have some local web pages that we need to access, which require some Internet Explorer settings changed ( like trusted sites, display mixed content etc.), and on each PC we install, we need to do them manually, and I want to do it programatically, with the help of Python, which is the only language i'm average at. Which is the best way to do this, is there some library to acces settings tab on IE, or the only hope is to search for each registry key for each setting and change it? Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for **specific technical problems**, as such I believe this is off-topic ([help/on-topic]). As for your question, I would be quite surprised if Python were the only or the best choice for this. For example, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [_winreg module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) (python 2 version) or [winreg module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) (python 3 version) to handle the registry.

Python sample code as below:
The following code will set the user shell folders (Microsoft Edge Download folder)

```
import winreg
key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders')
winreg.SetValueEx(key,'{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'D:\TempData')
key.Close()
```

Besides, here is an article about the [IE browser registry](https://getadmx.com/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::DefaultTilesView), you could check it.